# What is the PHP code for generating password hash, so that it can be compared from Node.js API service

Tags: php, node.js, bcrypt, password-hash

Salt and hash password using bcrypt in Node.js code is given below:

```
const password = "admin12345678";
const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
```

*passwordHash* is stored in the database. 
Do I need to save the salt to the database, for checking comparison in PHP? Is it secure though?

Comparison code in Node.js is as follows.

```
const password   = "admin12345678";
let passwordHash = '$2y$10$jRSNwj.vWLCT/chY4mCTvOuCqOv5PsmVgvektqRQW5BdbMXmZQyZi' // Generated above
if (await bcrypt.compare(password, passwordHash)) { // This works fine_
    res.send('LoggedIn');
} else {
    res.send('Not Valid User!');
}
```

PHP equivalent code to generate password hash is given below.

```
$password = 'admin12345678';
echo $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

Output:

```
$2y$10$0/umkIdTD0PePbtJAP/Z5u7qxOgz8wTn9ZYa5srNqDcLyqp3F7MEC
```

Node.js compare hash password generated by PHP

```
const password   = "admin12345678";
let passwordHash = '$2y$10$0/umkIdTD0PePbtJAP/Z5u7qxOgz8wTn9ZYa5srNqDcLyqp3F7MEC' // Generated by PHP
if (await bcrypt.compare(password, passwordHash)) { // This failed :(
    res.send('LoggedIn');
} else {
    res.send('Not Valid User!');
}
```

When I compare the hashed password generated by PHP in Node.js it doesn’t work. I need to work the hash password generated by PHP to get compared on Node.js and vice versa.